# How can I edit javascript code inside html file using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup, gmplot

My problem is actually very simple, but cant find any ways of fixing it. I have a python program that generates an html file containing a map, using the gmplot lib. I wish to remove some overlays automatically drawn by gmplot, and ppl told me there's no Python function/tool to do that.
When you look at the html generated file code, in order to do what I wish, the modification is rather very simple: at every match of the string `"map: map"`, replace with `"map: map, suppressMarkers: true"`

I've searched everywhere, it seems like common sense would be using BeautifulSoup to do it, thing is these "map: map" strings are inside a javascript script in the html file, which always ends up returning me "NoneType".

I thought I'd be able to fix this in a couple mins, but it's already been many hours and can't find a way.
To whoever has the answers to this simple but tricky problem, many thanks :)

Comment: This may be a hacky solution, but can you just do a string replace? It looks like a unique string that may not occur elsewhere

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from replacing the strings in the generated file using regex?

Comment: Thanks guys, the string replacement was what I did and it worked. For anyone with this problem, just do the following:

file = open('map.html').read()

replaced_txt = file.replace('map: map', 'map: map, suppressMarkers: true')

writer = open(map.html','w')

writer.write(replaced_txt)

writer.close()